# python- How to compute the equipotential lines of a vector field?

Tags: python, vector, field, lines, curve

I have a vector field and I am plotting it with quiver. This is, I have the positions of the vector field stored in X ,Y and the components of the field stored in U (x-component), V (y-component). And I am plotting the vector using

```
axes.quiver(X,Y, U, V, angles='xy', scale_units='xy')
```

Now I want to plot some equipotential lines. I know that these lines must be perpendicular to the field at each point, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The potential associated to a vector function is E=-grad V . E reprensent your vectorial function and "grad" is an operator that consists in derivating the E function with one parameter and setting the other as constants multiple times. V is the potential.

Here's an example of a grad operator (pronouce gradient):

f(x,y)=2*x+y**2

grad f = df/dx vx + df/dy vy = 2 vx + 2*y vy (grad, vx and vy are vectors)

so, you have to integrate your vector field in order to find the x,y,z components of your potential. then, just plot the points that have a similar potential. If you can't find a potential, it means there isn't any.